# Validar inputs type="file" con arreglo en atributo "name" con Jquery validate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un inconveniente intentando validar unos inputs type="file" con jquery validate, enumero los peros:

1. Como todos los inputs no son requeridos (solo 1 y 2) el campo `name` se rellena con un arreglo desde php al momento de enviar. Por eso el... `(name="attachment[]")`
2. Al momento de validar, no me toma la validación , `rules/messages`, en Jquery validate; supongo que tengo que usar los ID, pero no se como hacerlo.

La idea es validar tanto que sea obligatorios **el input 1 y 2**, y verificar que en **todos los inputs se cumpla la condición** del formato de archivos al momento de subir.

```js
$('#contact-form').validate({
  rules: {
    attachment: {required: true, extension: "jpg|png|pdf"}
    },
  messages: {
    attachment: {
      required: "Seleccione un archivo",
      extension: "Formato de archivo incorrecto"
    },
  },
  // desde aqui se procesa el envio
  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
  },
  success: function(element) {
    element
    // .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="regFila1">
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="fdui" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" required /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="rdui" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" required /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="const" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="bill" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" /><br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="send" value="ENVIAR" />
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Necesariamente lo tienes que hace con jQuery Validate? Usando solo jQuery sería relativamente sencilla la solución

Comment: @anythingg no tengo preferencia por uno o el otro, si con jquery basta para mí está bien, pensándolo bien también necesito validar si el archivo pesa mas de 2Mb

Comment: Hola @Elboy, ¿qué es exactamente lo que quieres hacer? Es decir, ¿podrías dar un poco más de contexto sobre que lo que quieres lograr? Por ejemplo, si colocas varios **inputs** porque quieres permitir al usuario enviar múltiples archivos y la cantidad mínima a enviar son dos archivos.

Comment: ¿O simplemente, esos **inputs** son para cada tipo de envío? Si lo que quieres es permitir al usuario enviar múltiples archivos puede utilizar un solo `input file`. Esos múltiples archivos lo podría entender el servidor como un **array**. Si ese es el caso, podrías colocar un nombre seguido de un par de corchetes (`[]`), por ejemplo, `name="archivo[]"` y establecer el atributo `multiple`.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Cada input es para un archivo específico, pero solamente 2 son obligatorios; Documentos: (Frente, reverso), el resto es para otros comprobantes pero que no siempre tiene a mano el usuario asi que puede gestionarse su obtención una vez iniciado el proceso, logré realizar las validaciones en la entrada que coloqué mas abajo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He hecho algunas modificaciones y he logrado que realice la validación del tipo de archivo y el peso (lo aumente a 3mb), parece funcionar bien. [según esta entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096591/validate-file-extension-and-size-before-submitting-form)

Adicionalmente modifiqué una función del archivo jquery.validate.js, encontre info [en esta entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670447/how-to-validate-array-of-inputs-using-validate-plugin-jquery)

```
checkForm: function() {
    this.prepareForm();
    for (var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++) {
      if (this.findByName(elements[i].name).length != undefined && this.findByName(elements[i].name).length > 1) {
        for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.findByName(elements[i].name).length; cnt++) {
          this.check(this.findByName(elements[i].name)[cnt]);
        }
      } else {
        this.check(elements[i]);
      }
    }
    return this.valid();
}
```

Para que **solo los dos primeros campos sean obrigatorios**, no declaro la condición en jquery validate, solamente el mensaje de error. En su lugar coloco el parámetro `required` en los 2 primeros inputs del formulario, de esta forma hrml5 se encargará de gestionarlos.

```js
// Regla para validar tamaño máximo de archivo
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
}, 'File size must be less than {0}');

$('#contact-form').validate({
  rules: {
    'attachment[]': {
      // required: true, // dejar que html5 gestione esta parte
      accept: "jpg,jpeg,png,pdf",
      filesize: 3145728
    },
  }, // end rules
  messages: {
    'attachment[]': {
    required: 'Debes adjuntar un archivo',
    accept: 'Formato de archivo no soportado',
    filesize: 'El tamaño máximo permitido es de 3mb'
    }
  }, // end messages

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<body>
<form action="" id="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="regFila1">
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="fdui" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" required/><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="rdui" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" required/><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="const" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="bill" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" /><br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="send" value="ENVIAR" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

No se puede apreciar correctamente que todos los campos están validados ya que no encontré como incrustar el fragménto de código para editar el archivo `jquery.validate.js`, así que lo edité directamente.

Answer (score 1):

La solución es relativamente sencilla, solo usa los atributos HTML:

```html
<form action="" id="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="regFila1">
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="fdui" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" required /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="rdui" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" required /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="const" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="bill" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" /><br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="send" value="ENVIAR" />
</form>
```

De manera, que dos son requeridos, pero todos aceptan archivos *.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf*

Si tienes un gran número de inputs, lo puedes hacer con una función, para recorrer cada elemento del formulario

```js
function ValidationInit(formSelector, inputType, rules) {
  try {
    document.querySelectorAll(formSelector).forEach(form => {
      form.querySelectorAll("input, textarea").forEach(el => {
        Object.entries(rules).forEach(entry => {
          const [key, value] = entry;
          if (el["type"] === inputType) {
            el.setAttribute(key,value);
          }
        });
      });
    });
    return true;
  } catch(exp) {
    return exp;
  }
}

ValidationInit("#contact-form", "file", {accept:".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf"});
```

```html
<form action="" id="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="regFila1">
    <input type="file" id="fdui" required /><br>
    <input type="file" id="rdui" required /><br>
    <input type="file" id="const" /><br>
    <input type="file" id="bill" /><br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="send" value="ENVIAR" />
</form>
```

Recibimos un selector, haremos un *Try / Catch*, ya que podremos detectar excepciones y devolverlas, además, recorreremos todos los *inputs* y *textareas* del elemento con dicho selector, finalmente aplicaremos algunas reglas a los elementos

Ahora, teniendo esto, como dices, necesitas saber si algún archivo pesa más de 2MB

Podemos obtener el peso del archivo subido con `.size`, una manera rápida sería insertar el `.size` de cada input en un array y usar el método `.some` para comprobar si existe algún elemento superior a los 2MB

```js
document.querySelector("#contact-form").addEventListener("submit", e => {
  const sizes = [];
  document.querySelectorAll("#contact-form input").forEach(el => {
    if (el.type !== "file") return;
    if(!el.files[0]) return sizes.push("undefined");
    let _size = el.files[0].size;
    let fSExt = new Array('Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'),
    i=0;while(_size>900){_size/=1024;i++;}
    let exactSize = (Math.round(_size*100)/100)+' '+fSExt[i];
    sizes.push(exactSize);
  });
  if(sizes.some(el=>(el.replace(" MB", "") - 0) >= 2)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Solo se admiten archivos inferiores a 2MB");
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="regFila1">
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="fdui" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" required /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="rdui" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" required /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="const" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="bill" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" /><br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="send" value="ENVIAR" />
</form>
```

Obtenemos el peso del archivo, luego lo insertamos en un array, finalmente podemos obtener

```
X KB
X MB
```

Por eso lo reemplazamos

```
el.replace(" MB", "")
```

Nos quedaría solo *X*, donde *X* es un número convertible con `-0` (un string no puede ser restado con un entero, por lo que se convertirá a un entero), al tener ya el número, simplemente comprobamos que sea mayor que 2, y de serlo hace un `preventDefault` para evitar que se proceda con el envío del formulario, el *parseInt* dará NaN si el archivo pesa menos de 1MB

Finalmente, para mostrar un mensaje al usuario, podemos usar una clase de CSS y un `::after` para poner el mensaje, también marcaremos los campos requeridos con un atributo `data-required`

```js
document.querySelector("#contact-form").addEventListener("submit", e => {
  const sizes = [];
  document.querySelectorAll("#contact-form input").forEach(el => {
    if (el.type !== "file") return;
    if(!el.files[0]) return sizes.push({size:"0",elem:el});
    let _size = el.files[0].size;
    let fSExt = new Array('Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'),
    i=0;while(_size>900){_size/=1024;i++;}
    let exactSize = (Math.round(_size*100)/100)+' '+fSExt[i];
    sizes.push({size:exactSize,elem:el});
  });
  sizes.forEach(el => {
    if(el.size === "0") {
      if (el.elem.getAttribute("data-required")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        el.elem.classList.add("needsValidation");
      }
    }
    if ((el.size.replace(" MB", "")) - 0 >= 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
      el.elem.classList.add("fileSizeExceded");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  padding:8px;
  border:solid 1px #c6c6c6c1;
  border-radius:8px;
  display:block;
  transition:0.3s;
  -webkit-transition:0.3s;
  -moz-transition:0.3s;
  -o-transition:0.3s;
}

.needsValidation,.fileSizeExceded {
  border:solid 1px red;
}

.needsValidation::after {
  content:"Este campo es obligatorio";
  color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:25px;
}

.fileSizeExceded::after {
  content:"Solo se admiten archivos menores a 2MB";
  color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:25px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:980px) {
  .needsValidation::after,.fileSizeExceded::after {
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="regFila1">
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="fdui" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" data-required="t" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="rdui" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" data-required="t" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="const" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="bill" accept=".jpg,jpeg,.png,.pdf" /><br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="send" value="ENVIAR" />
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por el detalle, con respecto al tamaño máximo de archivo, me funciona, pero en consola arroja lo siguiente "Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null" Supongo que es porque estoy llenando subiendo solo 2 archivos. La primera parte, la validación del formato no me funciona, y aunque tenga como required en el html, con solo adjuntar el primero se envia el formulario.

Comment: @Elboy ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo reproducible de lo que tienes? Así podré ver que está fallando, arreglarlo y explicarlo

Comment: Ayer me puse a indagar un poco más sobre jquery validate y logré algunas cosas, dejo lo que ha logrado, solo tengo unos inconvenientes para validar después del primer archivo